# Kafka msql connector configuration file doesnot work when query is not provided

Tags: mysql, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I have a configuration file for Kafka which reads data from MYSQL database perfectly fine

```
name=local-jbdc
connector.class=io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector
connection.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/book
connection.user=root
connection.password=newpass
topic.prefix=quickstart-events
mode=incrementing
incrementing.column.name=__id
query=select * from book_table
offset.flush.timeout.ms=5000
buffer.memory=200
poll.interval.ms=10000
tasks.max=1
```

Now when I take out the `query` and provide `table.whitelist` it doesnot read anything. Not even error.

The confiuration is shown below

```
name=local-jbdc
connector.class=io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector
connection.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/book
connection.user=root
connection.password=newpass
topic.prefix=quickstart-events
mode=incrementing
incrementing.column.name=__id
table.whitelist=book_table
offset.flush.timeout.ms=5000
buffer.memory=200
poll.interval.ms=10000
tasks.max=1
```

Can someone help me understand the root cause of this problem. Also how will I be able to do incremental mode for multiple tables.

Edits

When I stop the kafka with Ctrl+C on keyboard

there is a log coming up like this

````
[2020-11-30 12:35:38,057] INFO [ReplicaManager broker=0] Shut down completely (kafka.server.ReplicaManager)
[2020-11-30 12:35:38,058] INFO Shutting down. (kafka.log.LogManager)
[2020-11-30 12:35:38,106] INFO [ProducerStateManager partition=connect-status-4] Writing producer snapshot at offset 394 (kafka.log.ProducerStateManager)
[2020-11-30 12:35:38,158] INFO [ProducerStateManager partition=__consumer_offsets-18] Writing producer snapshot at offset 1 (kafka.log.ProducerStateManager)
[2020-11-30 12:35:38,219] INFO [ProducerStateManager partition=quickstart-eventsbook_table-0] Writing producer snapshot at offset 19645 (kafka.log.ProducerStateManager)
[2020-11-30 12:35:38,239] INFO [ProducerStateManager partition=quickstart-book_table-0] Writing producer snapshot at offset 2652 (kafka.log.ProducerStateManager)```
````

Comment: Anything interesting in logs?

Comment: The logs are clean. Are there any cases when issues like this happen that you know of.Or is it because Iam running in standalone mode! Or is there anyother way to configuration I could write to make it work?

Comment: @IskuskovAlexander Any thoughts on this

Comment: Could you try to run in distributed mode?

Comment: @IskuskovAlexander It is pretty much the same. When query parameter is provided it pulls data but when there is no query parameter it just stays the same.

Comment: Did you try enabling debug in the kafka connect log and run to see more information? sometimes you will see warning message like "WARN No tasks will be run because no tables were found (io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector)"

Comment: If there are no errors/warning, I hope you are looking for data in the right topic quickstart-eventsbook_table. topic.prefix property purpose - Prefix to prepend to table names to generate the name of the Apache Kafka® topic to publish data to, or in the case of a custom query, the full name of the topic to publish to.

Comment: @sramu I have added the log data. Does this mean that this it is getting written.

Comment: @IskuskovAlexander Does the added logs makes any sense to you

Comment: @VishnuChalil Can you see topic "quickstart-eventsbook_table" in the kafka cluster ? if yes, can you consume data from it ?if yes, everything looks fine.

Comment: @sramu Yes..I was reading from wrong topic and it works now. But what if I want all the data from tables to be read and put in a single topic. Is there any work around for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was pretty simple. When provided table.whitelist the connector creates a topic with the `topic.prefix` appended to the table name. In my case it created a new topic named `quickstart-eventsbook_table`. When query is provided `topic.prefix` is treated as the topic to send data too.